# How to get data by a condition and sum of every row with another condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 5 columns `ReportId, Date, Area, BuildingName, Amount`.

Sample data looks like this :

```
-------------------------------------------------------
ReportId |    Date    | Area | BuildingName | Amount
-------------------------------------------------------
   1     | 01/01/2013 |  S1  |    A1-01     |   5
   2     | 01/01/2013 |  S1  |    A1-03     |   5
   3     | 01/01/2013 |  S2  |    A1-05     |   4
   4     | 02/01/2013 |  S2  |    A1-05     |   7
   5     | 02/01/2013 |  S2  |    A1-03     |   9
   6     | 03/01/2013 |  S1  |    A1-03     |   2
   7     | 04/01/2013 |  S2  |    A1-02     |   6
   8     | 05/01/2013 |  S1  |    A1-01     |   7
   9     | 06/01/2013 |  S1  |    A1-02     |   5
   10    | 06/01/2013 |  S1  |    A1-05     |   8
   11    | 06/01/2013 |  S1  |    A1-07     |   5
```

I need to write a query to get the result like this :

```
-----------------------------------------------------
    Date    | Area   | BuildingName | Amount | Sum
-----------------------------------------------------
 01/01/2013 |    S1  |    A1-01     |   5    |  12
 01/01/2013 |    S1  |    A1-03     |   5    |  7
 01/01/2013 |    S2  |    A1-05     |   4    |  11
```

`Date` value passed as a parameter to the query.

"Area", "BuildingName", "Amount" are records which have the same "Date".

"Sum", is Sum of All "Amount" in the table where has the  same "Area" And "BuildingName" in the result of query.

I searched much, but I can't get anything about this ...

Comment: This looks a like a basic aggregate query. Min(Date), Max(Amount) and then group by the rest of the columns.

Comment: @SeanLange not Min(Date)... Date should pass to query. It can be any date ...

Comment: From your sample and the expected output that is the best guess I could make. It is not clear what you are trying to do as no matter you spin it the expected output doesn't really make a lot of sense.

Comment: Yeah.  He's just missing the record 11 in the sum for S1, A1-01.  If I understand correctly, it should be a 17 instead of a 12.

Comment: @MattH Yes... Unfortunately mistake again... I'm really sorry about these mistakes ... I changed record 11 from A1-01 to A1-07

Comment: @MohammadKhandordi  Not a problem. :)  We're here to help.  I added an answer below that lets you create and try this exact scenario.  Give it a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query

```
    SELECT @Date AS 'Date'
        ,t.Area
        ,t.BuildingName
        ,t.Amount
        ,temp.SumAmount
 FROM TABLE t INNER JOIN (SELECT Area, 
                                 BuildingName,
                                 SUM(Amount) 'SumAmount'
                          FROM TABLE t
                          GROUP BY Area, BuildingName) temp 
        ON temp.Area=t.Area AND 
          temp.BuildingName=t.BuildingName
Where t.Date= @Date
```

Comment: This code was great to find out the solution ...I did some adjustment and solved ... "WHERE Date = @Date" on line 10 cause "SumAmount" and "Amount" even. tnx alot for helping ... all people. all answers was very helpful and inspiring....

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
;with filter as (
    select Date, Area, BuildingName, Amount
    from data
    where data.Date = @date
)
select
     filter.Date
    ,filter.Area
    ,filter.BuildingName
    ,filter.Amoount
    ,sum(data.Amount) as [Sum]
from data
join filter
   on filter.Area         = data.Area
  and filter.BuildingName = date.BuildingName
group by
     filter.Date
    ,filter.Area
    ,filter.BuildingName
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot.

```
--Create table to test with and add in values
CREATE TABLE #tbl1 (ReportID int, [date] date, [area] varchar(2), BuildingName varchar(5), [Amount] int)
INSERT INTO #tbl1 VALUES(1, '20130101', 'S1', 'A1-01', 5)
INSERT INTO #tbl1 VALUES(2, '20130101', 'S1', 'A1-03', 5)
INSERT INTO #tbl1 VALUES(3, '20130101', 'S2', 'A1-05', 4)
INSERT INTO #tbl1 VALUES(4, '20130201', 'S2', 'A1-05', 7)
INSERT INTO #tbl1 VALUES(5, '20130201', 'S2', 'A1-03', 9)
INSERT INTO #tbl1 VALUES(6, '20130301', 'S1', 'A1-03', 2)
INSERT INTO #tbl1 VALUES(7, '20130401', 'S2', 'A1-02', 6)
INSERT INTO #tbl1 VALUES(8, '20130501', 'S1', 'A1-01', 7)
INSERT INTO #tbl1 VALUES(9, '20130601', 'S1', 'A1-02', 5)
INSERT INTO #tbl1 VALUES(10, '20130601', 'S1', 'A1-05', 8)
INSERT INTO #tbl1 VALUES(11, '20130601', 'S1', 'A1-01', 5)
--Declare the date variable you mentioned you wanted to "Pass in"
DECLARE @passedInDate date
set @passedInDate = '20130101'

--Here's the code that matters
select [Date], area, BuildingName, Amount
, (SELECT SUM(Amount) from #tbl1 [sq] where sq.area = tbl1.area and sq.BuildingName = tbl1.BuildingName) as [Sum]
from #tbl1 tbl1
where [DATE] = @passedInDate

--Drop testing table
Drop Table #tbl1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window version of `SUM` to get the sum of every `Area, BuildingName` partition. Then, in an outer query just filter by date, to get the required result set:

```
SELECT [Date], Area, BuildingName, Amount, [Sum]
FROM (
   SELECT [Date], Area, BuildingName, Amount,
          SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY Area, BuildingName) AS [Sum]
   FROM mytable ) t
WHERE [Date] = '01/01/2013'
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ffcab/1)

Answer (score 0):

**we can achieve the same result by using Row_number and Not in condition In CTE and while doing sum of amount 'A1-01' getting 17 but in your output you have mentioned 12...if you execute all the answers with same data you are going to get sum = 17 only for 'AI-01' .SO PLEASE CHECK IN YOUR DATA**

```
DECLARE @tbl1 TABLE  (ReportID int, [date] date, [area] varchar(2), BuildingName varchar(5), [Amount] int)
INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES(1, '20130101', 'S1', 'A1-01', 5)
INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES(2, '20130101', 'S1', 'A1-03', 5)
INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES(3, '20130101', 'S2', 'A1-05', 4)
INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES(4, '20130201', 'S2', 'A1-05', 7)
INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES(5, '20130201', 'S2', 'A1-03', 9)
INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES(6, '20130301', 'S1', 'A1-03', 2)
INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES(7, '20130401', 'S2', 'A1-02', 6)
INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES(8, '20130501', 'S1', 'A1-01', 7)
INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES(9, '20130601', 'S1', 'A1-02', 5)
INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES(10, '20130601', 'S1', 'A1-05', 8)
INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES(11, '20130601', 'S1', 'A1-01', 0)

;WITH CTE AS (
select 
DATE,
area,
buildingname,
amount,RN,R 
       from (
select 
    DATE,
    area,
    buildingname,
    amount,
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Area ORDER BY date,buildingname)RN,
SUM(AMOUNT)over(PARTITION by buildingname,area  )R from @tbl1)A

WHERE RN in( 1,2) )

select  
            DATE,
            Area,
            Buildingname,
            Amount,R  
   FROM CTE WHERE DATE NOT  IN (SELECT MAX(DATE)D FROM CTE C)
```